# C# Downloading unknown file to specific path and changing extension

Tags: c#

Trying to download file to specific path, and rename extension.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string newid = Convert.ToString(id);
    string file = client.DownloadFile("https://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=" + newid);
  Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".png");

}
```

I've tried a few solutions, and haven't found any more.

Comment: `It doesn't work`  Neither does your post.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void DownloadFile(
    string address,
    string fileName
)
```

> **Parameters**
>
> *address* Type: System.String The URI from which to download data.
>
> *fileName* Type: System.String The name of the local file that is to
>   receive the data.

So your code should look like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    String newid = id.ToString();
    String uri = "https://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=" + newid;
    String path = @"C:\MyFolder\Asset_" + newid + ".png";

    client.DownloadFile(uri, path);
}
```